# Attachment Sent to Kindle From Google Appengine not being Recognized

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, kindle

Using the code below I am trying to send an attachment to my Kindle from an Appengine App.

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
     import cStringIO
     out=cStringIO.StringIO()
     out.write('Hello, World!')

     reading = mail.EmailMessage(
          sender='[sender email]',
          subject='convert',
          to=[list or recipient emails], 
          attachments=[('test.txt', out.getvalue())])

     reading.send()
```

However, Amazon replies with

> Your email to Kindle(s) did not include any attachments

Next I tried adding my email to the list of recipients and I get the email with the attachment just fine.

How come Amazon doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to send a .TXT file, but that's not a supported file type.

From [Amazon's documentation](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=kinw_myk_pd_ln?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200767340):

> Kindle Personal Documents Service supports multiple file types, including:
>
> - Microsoft Word (.DOC, .DOCX)
> - HTML (.HTML, .HTM)
> - RTF (.RTF)
> - JPEG (.JPEG, .JPG)
> - Kindle Format (.MOBI, .AZW)
> - GIF (.GIF)
> - PNG (.PNG)
> - BMP (.BMP)
> - PDF (.PDF)